# What does the Kanji on this t-shirt say?

Tags: characters

[image: One Piece t-shirt with Kanji text]

I received this t-shirt as a gift, but I have no idea what the text says. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have 霸王色 (bà​wáng​sè). 霸王龙 （bà​wáng​lóng） is Chinese for Tyrannosaurus Rex! 霸王 （bà​wáng） is a despot, one who rules by might rather than right! Is that you?

Answer (score 1):

it's the manga "one-piece", with illustration of "luffy".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece

the three characters is "霸王色" ( はおうしょくのはき ), the highest form of ability (or awareness)?

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONE_PIECEの用語一覧](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONE_PIECE%E3%81%AE%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)

Answer (score 0):

In the anime One Piece, it means Conqueror's Haki or Haoshoku Haki:

**Haoshoku Haki is a rare form of Haki that cannot be attained through training. Only one in several million people have this ability. This type of Haki allows the user to exert their willpower over others. It is said that whoever possesses this type of Haki has the qualities of a king.**

[Haoshoku Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki)